# Filter by date range OR member ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to filter the data either by date range or by member ID. Below is what I have tried but it returns page not found.

[image]

I been tried many ways but still can't display out the data. The route url to blade is all correct however it just not displaying the blade file. It is something wrong in my controller codes?

**Controller**

```
$members = Membership::with(['profile'])
    ->when($request->memberId, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->value . '%');
    })
    ->when($request->dateStarted, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $dateS = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->dateStarted));
        $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $dateS);
    })
    ->when($request->dateEnded, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $dateE = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->dateEnded));
        $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $dateE);
    })
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(15);
```

**Route**

`Route::get('/members-listing', [$ControllerClass, 'memberListing'])->('members-listing');`

and below is the **script** to call the api through route url

```
<script>
            function generate() {
                var route = '{{ route('members-listing') }}';
                var filterBy = $('select[name="filter-by"]').val();
                var memberId = $('input[name="member-id"]').val();
                var dateStarted = $('input[name="date-started"]').val();
                var dateEnded = $('input[name="date-ended"]').val();

                if (filterBy != null && filterBy == "filter-lead-id") {
                    route = route + '&filterBy=' + filterBy + '&leadId=' + leadId;
                } else if (filterBy != null && filterBy == "filter-date") {
                    route = route + '&filterBy=' + filterBy + '?dateStarted=' + dateStarted + '&dateEnded=' + dateEnded;
                }

                window.location.href = route;
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#filter-date").hide();
                $('#filter-by').change(function() {
                    $('.filter').hide();
                    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Why did you use where LIKE for your id ? ID is unique number, If user input is 1 it will find 11, 12, 33331 etc. Can you add your js code to make the request? And route file to see if the page is correct

Comment: the route in my js code goes to the right page, however it's still 404

Comment: route('members-listing') this searches for url by name but your route does not have name. Add - >name('members-listing') at the end of your route line for this routr

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = Membership::with(['profile']);

if(isset($request->memberId) && !empty($request->memberId))
{
    $query->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->value . '%');
}

if(isset($request->dateStarted) && !empty($request->dateStarted))
{
    $dateS = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->dateStarted));
    $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $dateS);
}

if(isset($request->dateEnded) && !empty($request->dateEnded))
{
    $dateE = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->dateEnded));
    $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $dateE);
    
}

$query->latest()->paginate(15);
```

Comment: It is not about the query.